# Laravel blog post sample

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm trying to make a system to post blog posts to my web page, I can get it to show the content from the database but if I want to limit the amount of characters to display.

```
@foreach ($pages as $post)
    <div class="post">
        <h4>{{ $post->title}}</h4>
        <?php
            $content = html_entity_decode($post->body); 
        ?>
        <p>{!!html_entity_decode($post->body)!!}</p>
        <p>{{ str_limit($content, $limit = 300, $end = '...') }}</p>
    <div>
@endforeach
```

So the first `<p>` tag works but the characters are not limited, the second will limit the amound of characters but it will display with the HTML tags. I've just picked up laravel so I'm not sure why this is not working as is.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to anyone looking in the future, PHP has a function called strip_tags().

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php